# Can you export data from the Polls module in Orchard CMS

Tags: .net, orchardcms

Researching the right .NET CMS to pick for a small project. Is there an easy way to export the results of a poll to a spreadsheet? I could see this happening as either a feature of the Polls module, or as a custom query with an export to excel (think Drupal's Views module).

Comment: Why was I downvoted? This is a totally legitimate question, which isn't clearly answered on the Orchard website, or in the description of the Polls module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by poll, or what Polls module you are referencing, but we have used Orchard Custom Forms to create a small question sheet for our users that we then download as a spreadsheet. Spreadsheet module was built in-house I believe. Pretty simple stuff.

But I think a module for exporting content to csv was recently released on the gallery: https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Dolph.ExportToCsv/1.1 and you can read about custom forms here: http://devdirective.com/post/160/how-to-create-custom-forms-in-orchard-cms-with-email-and-recaptcha , to see if this is what you are looking for.